# Change same signal at either rising or falling state of a signal

Tags: fpga, vhdl, synchronous

I am bit new to VHDL, and hope some of you guys could help me here.

I trying to establish a connection between an ADC, LED, and control component.

The purpose of this application is to convert an analog value measured on the ADC, and then output to the LED.

The way i've designed the communication is as follows.

The LED set and signal high (`start_adc`) Which the ADC read, and start the ADC.

When the ADC is done, it sets the signal `read` high, which Control then reads, and then read the `ADC_value` ( a binary value - std_logic_vector (9 down to 0)).

This `ADC_value` is kept within control, but the LED has to change its state. So Control set the signal `next_state` high, which LED reads and changes its state to something  else.  The problem here is how do i turn off `next_state`?.

My solution entailed the use of a signal named `received` which would be set high, if an `rising_egde(next_state)`was seen such that, if control saw an `rising_edge(received)`, it could then turn off `next_state`and then when LED shaw and `falling_edge(next_state)` it could set `received` low again, and then `start_adc` high.

code wise it looks like this

```
state_changer: process(clk,state)
variable count: integer range 0 to 500000000 :=0;
begin
     if falling_edge(next_state) then
       received <= '0'; 
       start_adc <= '1';
     elsif rising_edge(next_state) then 
       received <= '1';
        count := 0;
        start_adc <= '0';
     end if; 
     count := count +1;  
end process;
```

but as you can see the problem is that the same signal is set either at rising and falling..  how do I work around this issue?..

Notice `count` is also important.

Comment: Unless you have a specialist CPLD, FPGAs only have single edge flip flops, they can't do things on both edges.

Comment: Generally you would simply have a clock which is twice as fast as you need, and then have a clock enable. The logic that needs to be done on both rising and falling is instead done on a rising edge of the fast clock. Every fast clock cycle your clock enable register toggles and you use that to determine when things that go at half the speed should be done.

Comment: I think though looking at your code you need to go back to basics. Start by drawing a state machine on paper of what your control signals need to do based on what inputs.

Comment: I resolved the issue, by using the read signal  `if read = '1' then next_state <= '0'; end if; `

Comment: As others noted, FPGAs only allow specific signals to be used as clocks. Sometimes you can do tricks with dedicated DDR primitives, but I think this is just a matter of your misunderstanding.

Comment: Isn't that just the same as `received <= next_state; start_adc <= not next_state;`?

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not complex... assuming your ADC code is working correctly..

you can use 2 edge detector circuit to generate a pulse: one on rising edge and one falling edge.. this will simplify your process...

http://fpgacenter.com/examples/basic/edge_detector.php

your process should have a reset condition and set initial value for the variables...

Answer (score 0):

I'd check if the FPGA has DDR logic in the I/O blocks, this is quite common. This would give you two signals per input pin, one sampled at rising edge, one sampled at falling edge.